# Diferença de ' ' e ` `

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou lendo o ng-book 2 sobre Angular 2 e em um dos exercícios surgiu uma dúvida. Ao configurar meu componente primeiro código não exibe os valores `title` e `link` no console, porém o segundo funciona perfeitamente.

O primeiro utiliza aspas simples. ' '. Já o segundo utiliza acentuação, . Qual a diferença e por que de não funcionar?

```
// Não Funciona    
addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link: HTMLInputElement): boolean{
        console.log('${title.value} ${link.value}');
        return false;
      }

// Funciona    
addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link: HTMLInputElement): boolean{
        console.log(`${title.value} ${link.value}`);
        return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As strings definidas com *backticks*/crases (`) permitem interpolação (embutir expressões no meio da string sem precisar fechar sua delimitação e concatená-la com outra string), multilinhas (não precisar escapar uma quebra de linha dentro da string ou concatenar duas strings em linhas diferentes) e processamento (*tagging*/*parse*, onde você pode usar uma função pré-definida).

Esta forma de definição é nativa do JavaScript e é chamada de *template literals* a partir do ES2015 e de *template strings* anteriormente. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Exemplos de uso de *template literals*:

```
`texto` # simples 'string text'

`texto linha 1
texto linha 2` # multilinha equivalente a 'texto linha 1\ntexto linha 2'

`texto ${variavel} texto` # interpolação

function tag(literais, ...expressoes) {
    let resultado = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < expressoes.length; i++) {
        resultado += literais[i];
        resultado += expressoes[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    resultado += literais[literais.length - 1];

    return resultado;
}

tag `texto ${variavel} texto` # parse
```

Answer (score 2):

Tanto no TypeScript quanto no [JavaScript a partir do ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) é possível usar o delimitador de *backtick*.

Com ele a *string* passa ser gabaritada, então pode colocar expressões de código dentro da própria *string*, além de poder continuá-la na linha seguinte, ou seja, ela faz interpolação da *string*.

Então o primeiro funciona, só não faz o que espera. Com aspas normais aquilo é um texto como outro qualquer, ele não interpreta como um trecho de código a ser executado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).