# Uso de ${variavel} em Javascript

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Estava lendo [este artigo](https://blog.especializati.com.br/como-fazer-requisicoes-ajax-com-o-axios/?fbclid=IwAR0opRq4L0_lwiK0JwnVx-MnwbkC68cNhvvvVt8fiPhe-0MDuX31qYjW1NA) sobre AJAX quando me deparei com essa forma de se usar uma variável dentro de uma string:

```
let cep = document.getElementById('cep').value;

axios.get('http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/${cep}')... // o ${cep} me lembra a sintaxe do php
```

Fiquei intrigado pois nunca vi esse modo de se usar uma variável, sabem me dizer se usa-se alguma biblioteca pra isso tipo jQuery ou tem suporte nativo do JavaScript?

Obs: Não consegui encontrar um termo certo pra pesquisar no Google então recorri aqui.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença de ' ' e \` \`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188004/diferen%c3%a7a-de-e)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso é uma especificação do ECMAScript introduzida na sua versão 5 com o nome de *template strings*, e a partir da versão 6 é chamada de *template literals*.

A sua principal função do *template literals* é a facilidade de montar string, podendo fazer expressões ou usar variáveis dentro de uma string, facilitando a leitura da mesma.

Por exemplo, ao invés de você concatená-la diretamente do jeito tradicional:

```js
var nome = 'João';
var string = 'Olá! ' + nome + ', você está usando o StackOverflow!';

alert(string);
```

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
var nome = 'João';
var string = `Olá!, ${nome}, você está usando o StackOverflow!`;
alert(string);
```

Neste caso, a expressão `${nome}` será substituída pelo conteúdo da variável correspondente, ficando muito mais fácil a sua leitura e sua manutenção.

Para mais informações sobre *template literals* veja esta [documentação.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Mas atenção, algumas versões de navegadores pode não suportar essa funcionalidade. Veja [aqui](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals) a lista completa de versões suportadas.

Para uma documentação técnica (em inglês), veja [aqui](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literals) no site oficial do ECMAScript.

Answer (score 5):

O nome desse recurso é `Template string`.

> [`Template String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)
>
> Template literals são literais string que permitem expressões embutidas. Você pode usar string multi-linhas e interpolação de string com elas. Elas eram chamadas "template strings" nas versões anteriores à especificação ES2015.
>
> **Sintaxe**
>
> ```
> `corpo de texto`
> `texto linha 1
>  texto linha 2`
> `texto string ${expression} texto string`
> tag `texto string ${expression} texto string`
> ```