# "For" 'lagando' interface

Tags: javascript, html, apache-cordova, for

Tenho um JSON que estou usando para gerar um HTML em um *app* Cordova da seguinte forma:

```
function gerarLista(lista) {

    strHtml = "";

    for(item in lista) {

            strHtml += '<div class="item">';

                strHtml += '<div class="descricao">' + lista[item].descricao + '</div>';

                strHtml += '<div class="imagem">';
                    strHtml += '<img src="' + lista[item].imagem + '" />';
                strHtml += '</div>';

                strHtml += '<div class="valor">' + lista[item].valor + '</div>';

            strHtml += '</div>';

    }


    $("#produtos").html(strHtml);

}
```

Para gerar uma lista pequena está tranquilo, porém quando tem uma quantidade de produtos maior a interface da uma travada quando eu chamo essa função, vejo isso porque quando essa função é chamada já tem uma animação css rodando.

Queria saber se tem algum modo melhor(em questão de performance) de gerar esse html? Pelo que entendi o `for` roda em tempo de execução então tem algum jeito de rodar ele de modo assíncrono ou sei lá, pra não ocorrer esse travamento?

Comment: Acredito que utilizando o https://handlebarsjs.com você possa fazer algo mais interessante. Ou então tentar algo com Interpolation string no javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Você pode tentar seguir a abordagem das frameworks modernas e atualizar apenas o que alterou, não mexendo nos produtos que permanecem iguais. Certamente implica mais lógica.

Comment: @Isac o problema é a primeira vez que vou criar esses elementos em que acontece o `lag`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript tem *strings* imutáveis, então incorre no problema chamado  [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101). Não digo que este seja o único problema, mas ele torna tudo terrível e acho que esta forma pode ajudar bem. Não garanto porque não conheço os detalhes da implementação do JS em cada *browser*, mas um usuário do site me mostrou em privado que há ganhos claros. Criando um *array* com espaço já predeterminado e preenchendo com textos em cada elemento e depois juntar tudo em uma só *string* tende a dar um ganho bem grande.

Ajuda também fazer com que pelo menos a *string* do laço seja uma só através de [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188004/101) (espero que isso seja feito internamente do jeito certo, mas é JS, então temo) que só não dá para usar em *browsers* muito antigos, ainda tem uma solução razoável sem isso usando o *array*.

```
function gerarLista(lista) {
    var array = new Array(lista.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        array[i] = `<div class="item">
            <div class="descricao">${lista[i].descricao}</div>
            <div class="imagem">
            <img src="${lista[i].imagem}" />
            </div>';
            <div class="valor">${lista[i].valor}</div>
            </div>`;
    }
    $("#produtos").html(array.join(""));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/BuildString.js).

Comment: Gostei dos artigos, vou fazer um teste com seu codigo. Mas saberia me dizer se esse `template string` ``` não vai dar problema com os aparelhos, esse app pretendo compilar pra IOS e Android(minimo versão 5)? O suporte dele é bom(dá pra usar sem ter medo de não funcionar nos aparelhos)?

Comment: Parece que tá tranquilo: https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20string.

Comment: Acredito que o código gerará alguns errors. No código original o autor usou o loop `for in` logo o argumento `lista` da função é do tipo `object` e não `array` e `object` não possui o atributo `length` usado na chamadas a `lista.length` em sua resposta. Dentro do loop, várias vezes foi usado `lista[item]` porém `item` nunca foi definido no escopa da resposta.

Comment: @Vinicius.Silva Nada diz que o uso do `for in` tem que ocorrer com um objeto que não possua tamanho, neste caso me parece que tem, se não tiver ele precisa falar algo sobre isso (na verdade é raro ter um objeto com vários elementos que não se sabe o tamanho), se ele disser que tem um objeto assim eu modifico o código para atender isso, o que complica o código, então só o farei se tiver necessidade. O nome da variável realmente eu comi bola e vou arrumar.

Comment: @Maniero Da [página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Why_Use_for...in) da própria mozila "Given that for...in is built for iterating object properties(...)". Na questão do `length` eu me referi ao uso a propriedade e não no comprimento do objeto. Faça o teste no console `var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }; console.log(obj.length); //undefined`

Comment: Você está falando de algo que não é o que ele tem no código dele, isso está bem claro. O seu código não tem elementos, apenas membros, é muito difícil construir um objeto que possui elementos e não ter a propriedade de tamanho. O código e descrição da pergunta dele deixa claro que o objeto acessa elementos, ainda que não esteja explicitado isso de forma inequívoca. Mas seria estranho algo chamado `lista` não ser uma lista e ser só um objeto simples. E seria estranho dar problema `quando tem uma quantidade de produtos maior`, então me parece que seja uma questão de interpretação de texto.

Comment: Concordo com seu ponto de vista. Se `lista` for realmente um array o código executará sem problemas.

Comment: Lista era um `Array[]`, rodou liso junto com umas outras otimizações.